# How to force play area corners to Lighthouses in Unity

Tags: unity, virtual-reality, htc-vive

I'm working for a guy that wants to recreate real environments in VR and superpose them for business demos. Think of one of those mall kiosks where you "enter virtual reality" and at first it looks exactly the same as regular reality until you start interacting with objects and the virtual elements start being superposed. Basically, AR in VR.

To do this, I have an exact model of the kiosk, but I need to be able to force the play area in vive and unity to be always the same and equal to the dimensions of the real space, so that my model can superpose the actual world objects. Is there a way to force the play area to be the same as the distance between the lighthouses?

Additionally, is there a way to force the lighthouses to never recalibrate after the initial setup(as it does when someone moves in front of them for example)?

Comment: People are going to be interacting with real world objects when they have the goggles on? I'm assuming stationary objects? You might consider a tracking puck to orient the room.

Comment: Can I do that with just the Vive? Or should I be looking into other tracking systems?

Comment: Yes, the tracking pucks are an accessory for the Vive. But you didn't answer my question.

Comment: Both your assumptions are correct.

Comment: The answer is extensive. I do not do this usually but this time is useful for you. Did you try the treehouse VR Unity tutorial? I think is exactlly what you are looking for. it explain how to setup and force the player area to be what you need.

Comment: @Althis Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I did not @Byte56, I ended up just switching to a marker system. It seemed easier to track real world position that way.

Comment: Like QR code style trackers? With a Vive?